# Sending Email Through localhost asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
     public ActionResult Index(EmailModel model)
    {

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("sheikh.abm@gmail.com");
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(model.To));

        message.Subject = model.Subject;
        message.Body = model.Message;


        return View();
    }
```

this is my controller action. And in web.config .

```
     <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="sheikh.abm@gmail.com">
        <network host="\localhost:"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

The problem i got is that the mail didn't send and it didn't show me any error kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to send the mail you will need to call the send method

e.g

```
message.Send();
```

Comment: after write that code i got that exception "SSL must not be enabled for pickup-directory delivery methods" .